# Disable body scroll when modal is open (`body { overflow: hidden }` does not work)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup, popupwindow

I'm trying to prevent the `body` from scrolling when a modal/popup is open.

There's a bunch of questions regarding this issue already but the answer to those question is always to add `{ overflow: hidden; }` to the `body` when a modal is open. But for some reason it does not work for me.

Adding `{ overflow: hidden; height: 100vh; }` disables the scrolling but now it jumps to the top of the page every time a modal is opened. `{ position: fixed; }` does the same thing.

What could be the reason that adding `{ overflow: hidden; }` to the `body` works for others but does not work for me? Are there any other ways to disable scrolling when a modal is open?

Comment: We could find out the reason but only if you would post your code, at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)...

Comment: when you add `{ overflow: hidden; }` to body, it limits the height of the page, so your scroll position is lost. that's why when you remove the overflow, it doesn't scroll back.

Comment: try changing `body{height: 100vh; overflow-y:hidden;}` when `modal` is open

Comment: @Shashank, same thing, does not work.

Comment: Please provide a sample of code here or else create a fiddle.